# Google sign in - package name appearing on dialog

Tags: android

I have integrated google sign in successfully. But the issue is when user tries to sign in into google, google's default user gmail accounts' dialog gets open from which user can select a account to login, the title appears on the dialog is package name instead of application's name ?

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. I had forgotten to put 'app name' param in manifest. 
But I am confused here that 'version code', 'version name' everything reads from gradle then why not 'app name' reads from gradle ? app name was mentioned in gradle in product flavor.